# I am unable to apply condition on cart price rule

Tags: magento2, admin

In cart price rule condition is not working properly at server
it showing a message won't take long and redirect to dashboard
while applying condition

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need also to reindex. Check your index status and if says "Reindex required", check your cron is running properly or you can force it from the command line:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I apply this changes then also it is not working

Comment: Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Comment: Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Comment: After that i got the above results

Comment: maybe the rule is not enabled? maybe is some internal problem (you could also check the logs)